# Background Script in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a script that runs in the background automatically and cycles through itself repeatedly. 
I'm accessing a websites API which does have a limit on number of requests per minute (1 every 2 seconds).  If I try to have this run as a normal PHP page it would take 28 hours to cycle through all the information that I want to collect.

I want to take this collected information and store it in a MySQL database so that I can access parts of it on a separate page later.

Is there a way that I can do this - have a constantly running script execute in the background on a web server? An I right in doing this in PHP, or should I be using another language. I have quite a bit of experience in PHP, but not so much in other languages. 
Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that the script tskes different amounts of time each run through - whether it be 27, or 28 hours.

Comment: You can edit the parameters of a cron job quite easily. Or you can make a new one each time, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have experience using cron jobs to handle background tasks?
You'd need shell access, but aside that it's pretty simple. Definitely more efficient when you don't need to output anything.

As for language - PHP is perfectly capable. This would depend on the processing, in my opinion. Supposing the API you are calling fetches images and processes them, resizing and so on. I might go with python if that;s the case, but I don't know what you're really up to.

Comment: The thing is that the script would take different lengths of time each run through. How would I reflect this varying length (and thus different start time)?

Comment: You could keep track via DB, using a fieled like "status" -> running, complete, etc and then your cron would only call the api if there are none in the DB with a status of running.